# Why such large degrees of freedom on some levels in a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, lme4, lmertest

I have activity budget data from wild orangutans for which I am investigating if there is a difference in the time they spend feeding, resting and travelling before a forest fire event and after the fire event. I am running a linear mixed effects model with the minutes spent feeding on a particular day as my response variable (with the number of minutes the orangutan is awake as an offset). Fire period and age/sex class are fixed effects, and orangutan ID is the random effect.
I have 2 levels of the fire_time factor ('pre' and 'post'), 4 levels of the Age_Sex factor ('SAF', 'FM', 'UFM', 'Adolescent'), 47 orangutans for the random effect and a total of 817 datapoints in this dataset.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
head(F)
   Follow_num Ou_name       Date  Month fire_time Age_Sex Primary_Act AP_obs minutesin24hr Perc_of_waking_day Perc_of_24hr
1        2029 Teresia 2011-10-04 Oct-11       pre     SAF     Feeding    625           310              49.60        21.53
5        2030 Teresia 2011-10-05 Oct-11       pre     SAF     Feeding    610           285              46.72        19.79
9        2032 Teresia 2011-10-09 Oct-11       pre     SAF     Feeding    620           340              54.84        23.61
13       2034 Teresia 2011-10-11 Oct-11       pre     SAF     Feeding    670           405              60.45        28.13
17       2038  Victor 2011-10-27 Oct-11       pre      FM     Feeding    675           155              22.96        10.76
21       2040    Nero 2011-11-03 Nov-11       pre      FM     Feeding    640           295              46.09        20.49
```

The code for my model is as follows:

```
library(lme4)

lmer(minutesin24hr ~ Age_Sex + fire_time + (1|Ou_name), data = F, offset = AP_obs, REML = TRUE, na.action = "na.fail")
```

When I run this model using the `lmerTest` package to check degrees of freedom and p-values, it seems I have very large degrees of freedom for the levels that are significant (see Age_SexSAF and fire_timepre).

`lmerTestmodel <- lmerTest::lmer(minutesin24hr ~ Age_Sex + fire_time + (1|Ou_name), data = F, offset = AP_obs, REML = TRUE, na.action = "na.fail")`

```
REML criterion at convergence: 9370.7
Scaled residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-3.8955 -0.6304  0.1006  0.7141  2.3109 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Ou_name  (Intercept) 1636     40.44   
Residual             5460     73.89   
Number of obs: 817, groups:  Ou_name, 47

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -188.614     14.711   26.765 -12.821 6.14e-13 ***
Age_SexFM     -20.297     17.978   24.696  -1.129   0.2698    
Age_SexSAF    -25.670     11.799  318.473  -2.176   0.0303 *  
Age_SexUFM     12.925     22.806   27.319   0.567   0.5755    
fire_timepre  -29.558      6.214  709.117  -4.757 2.38e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Ag_SFM A_SSAF A_SUFM
Age_SexFM   -0.741                     
Age_SexSAF  -0.505  0.374              
Age_SexUFM  -0.598  0.480  0.302       
fire_timepr -0.298 -0.015  0.149  0.034
```

I imagine these large degrees of freedom are making the p-values significant so am sceptical about the model. Why is it I am getting such large degrees of freedom on just these two levels? There are more data in the Age_SexSAF and fire_timepre levels but it doesn't seem normal to me.
I am planning on reporting the estimate, confidence intervals and p-values in my thesis but am concerned about reporting if these degrees of freedom are wrong.

Apologies if this may be a naïve question, this is the first time I have ventured into mixed effects models. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!